# VBA Access Pivot Chart set the y-axis min/max scale

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, pivot-chart

Came into another snag formating my Pivot Chart via VBA in Access 2010.  I get the "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

Again, I have tried many different iterations of the code, but can't get the right one.  As always, thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

'Call LineMarkerFormat

RONMax = DMax("[Total A/C]", "tblRONChartComparison")
RONMin = DMin("[Total A/C]", "tblRONChartComparison")

With Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).Axes(1).Scaling
    .MinimumScale = RONMin
    .MaximumScale = RONMax

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and the very next site I check had the very simple solution.  you no longer need the scaling on the end of the .minimum/.maximum.  Here is my working code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

'Call LineMarkerFormat

RONMax = DMax("[Total A/C]", "tblRONChartComparison")
RONMin = DMin("[Total A/C]", "tblRONChartComparison")


With Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).Axes(1).Scaling
    .Minimum = RONMin
    .Maximum = RONMax

End With

End Sub
```